# Check if current day is within two given weekdays

Tags: vb.net

A user can choose in a form a start day and an end day. (Let's say Friday til Monday.) 
How can I check whether the current weekday is in between these two weekdays?

```
Dim WEstart As DayOfWeek = 5 'Friday
Dim WEend As DayOfWeek = 1 'Monday

If Date.Now.DayOfWeek >= WEstart And Date.Now.DayOfWeek <= WEend Then
   Return True
Else
   Return False
End If
```

doesn't work right.

Comment: In this example, which days do you want to return `True`?

Comment: When you say your current code sample "doesn't work right", what does it do?  Have you tried putting in a breakpoint, stepping through it and seeing what your inputs and comparisons are?

Comment: As an aside, never make two comparisons to DateTime.Now like that - if you need to refer to "Now" more than once, load the value of DateTime.Now into a variable so that you can take a point in time snapshot to work with. Otherwise you can introduce subtle and hard to reproduce bugs (such as when your two invocations of Now fall each side of midnight).

Comment: @JamesWorld +1, very good point.

Answer (score 2):

try that. This checks for days between Friday and Monday. That is, it returns "True" for Friday, Saturday, Sunday and Monday.

If the day of week is Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it returns false.

```
Dim startday As DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday
    Dim endday As DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday
    Dim today As DayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek

    If endday >= startday Then
        Return (today >= startday AndAlso today <= endday)
    Else
        Return (today >= startday OrElse today <= endday)
    End If
```

Comment: `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And` and `Or` is generally a good idea, ’cause they short-circuit. Also, an `If` that only contains `Return True` and `Return False` doesn’t make much sense. You can just do `Return today >= startday AndAlso today <= endday`, e.g..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
Sub Main()
  Debug.WriteLine(IsBetween(Now, DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Friday))
End Sub

Function IsBetween(vDate As DateTime, startDay As DayOfWeek, endDay As DayOfWeek)
  If startDay <= endDay Then Return vDate.DayOfWeek >= startDay And
                                    vDate.DayOfWeek <= endDay
  Return vDate.DayOfWeek <= endDay Or vDate.DayOfWeek >= startDay
End Function
```